# bootstrap tabs not working in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

im having a problem with Bootstrap tabs in my jquery mobile app. I have 2 pages with 2 separate tabs.

When i load the page you will see 3 tabs in the body which says `Home, Menu 1, Menu 2` these tabs tabs works fine ([Demo Link](http://vidznet.com/testing/1.html)). on that page you will see View Map link which will take you to another page but if you notice the tabs dont work in that page (Not the tabs which says tab 1 , tab 2, tab 3). But when i refresh it works again. When i click on the Home link the tabs dont work there.

I have loaded the bootstrap file on all the pages in the header. I even tried moving them into `data-role="page"` But it still doesnt work.

If i disable the ajax it works, but i dont want to disable it. I need to keep the smooth transition between the pages

Below is the HTML code for the tabs

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo Link](http://vidznet.com/testing/1.html)

Can someone please tell me what might be causing it and how to fix it?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Inspecting your Demo code displays multiple errors.  You may want to consider presenting a demo that presents only the problematic code, so we can rule-out interference from some of the other assets you are loading.

Comment: @RobertC I modified the demo. Took off the extra JS libraries and removed the extra codes :)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it.. The problem was i had the same ID on the tabs. Although it was on 2 different pages, when i navigate to a different page on JQM it still linked the old the page tabs.

Once i changed the IDs to look different on both pages it started to work